# move the price in the shop page - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, position, price

In the main shop page (archive products) in woocommerce, I would like to get the price out of over the picture and put it simply under the product picture and it's title.

Thank you for your kind help,
Michal

[shop page woocommerce change position of price tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpvNg.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Comment: Hi there, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ---

```
remove_action(‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_price’, 10);

add_action(‘woocommerce_before_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_price’, 5);
```

You can move other information too. Source taken from [this artice](http://www.mingocommerce.com/move-product-title-above-the-thumbnail-in-product-page/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but nothing happens when I do that. The article deals with product page, if I understood correctly, but I need to change the archive page - the one with all the products.